# google chrome : http authentication issue on iframe

Tags: htaccess, http, google-chrome

I have an HTML file with 2 links both links are in an iframe to load the contents inside the iframe. I have two protected directories one on the same server and other on another server. If you click on either link it will popup the login box, same for both links in all browsers except google chorme. google chrome doesn't show login box for the protected folder on another server, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a website or code issue. It depends on the Google Chrome security settings so, leaving the code as is, there is nothing you can do because you can't control a user's browser.